# Excel index match array - showing all values in list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table as follows, the yellow box is a drop down to select the year 7, 8 or 9

[image]

The students list in col G shows all the students in the selected year (
yellow cell E2) using the following array formula (from G3 which is copied down):

```
{=INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$B$3:$B$9,COUNTIF($G$1:G2,$A$3:$A$9),""),0))}
```

My question is: What can I replace the yellow E2 cell with to show all names in the list regardless of year? I've tried `"*"` and it doesn't work. Is there a way around this without altering the formula?

Comment: Have you tried in this way `=IFERROR(IF($E$2="",$A$3:$A$9,INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$B$3:$B$9,COUNTIF($G$1:G2,$A$3:$A$9),""),0))),"")`

Comment: No, you will need to change the formula.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Many thanks, but if E2 is blank it just returns the first name in the list repeatedly. I've accepted I'll need to change the formula to deal with this:{=IF($E$2="all",INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2="all",COUNTIF(G$1:$H2,$A$3:$A$9),""),0)),INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$B$3:$B$9,COUNTIF(G$1:$H2,$A$3:$A$9),""),0)))}

Comment: @Slab this worked for me --> `=IF($E$2="",A3,INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$B$3:$B$9,COUNTIF($G$2:G2,$A$3:$A$9)),0)))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, ahhh yes changing from the range just to the single cell ref has done it! Many thanks

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya For me that's a valid answer that should be posted!

Comment: @Slab I have posted it as an answer, since it has worked for you, may accept/upvote as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have commented, and it has been accepted by OP as well as [Foxfire And Burns And Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns) Sir has mentioned its a valid one, hence posting it as an Answer,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **G3**

```
=IFERROR(IF($E$2="",A3,INDEX($A$3:$A$9,MATCH(0,IF($E$2=$B$3:$B$9,COUNTIF($G$2:G2,$A$3:$A$9)),0))),"")
```

Please note array entered formula needs to be entered with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` depending on Excel Versions.

Comment: It's good to have posted and accepted answers so in the future if any user read this post, it can get directly the answer instead of reading all comments! Upvoted